# Create an Upload File Button function on Web Studio

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I would like to request help on how I can create an upload file (JPG or PNG) function on the Web Studio form.

My client wants an upload file function button on the Web Studio / Smart Capture form.

The uploaded file must go to a specific folder on the Content Builder.

I have a very basic knowledge of AMPscript and am not sure how to build on this.

If you can create a sample or step guide that would be very helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no such function in AMPscript to upload a file from CloudPage to the Content Builder. The only similar by context would probably be the [AttachFile](https://ampscript.guide/attachfile/) function that attaches a file to the email that can be downloaded later.

First of all, to do that, it is better to have a custom CloudPage with a form in it that would do the same as your Smart Capture or Web Form does but will not restrict you to easily add your code on top.

In your case, you would need to do a bit more than to use one function to make it work. The main point would be to use [POST /asset/v1/content/assets](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/routes.htm#detail_CreateAsset) endpoint, which would upload the file to the Content Builder based on JSON values that you would need to generate and feed it to the endpoint. However, to make it all seamlessly on the WebForm/Smart Capture/CloudPage you would need to prepare many things before doing this call, e.g. encoding the image to Base64 format, fetch and retrieve back info, and only then tie everything up.

You can also check this [article](https://sfmarketing.cloud/2020/02/29/create-a-cloudpages-form-with-an-image-file-upload-option/) that would definitely help.